# detect your custom post type in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development

What properties of registered post type i required later to detect my post type in code. 
Suppose my code to register custom post type is below.

```
function dwwp_register_post_type() {

    $singular = __( 'Job Listing' );
    $plural = __( 'Job Listings' );
        //Used for the rewrite slug below.
        $plural_slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', $plural );

        //Setup all the labels to accurately reflect this post type.
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => $plural,
        'singular_name'         => $singular,
        'add_new'               => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New ' . $singular,
        'edit'                  => 'Edit',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit ' . $singular,
        'new_item'              => 'New ' . $singular,
        'view'                  => 'View ' . $singular,
        'view_item'             => 'View ' . $singular,
        'search_term'           => 'Search ' . $plural,
        'parent'                => 'Parent ' . $singular,
        'not_found'             => 'No ' . $plural .' found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No ' . $plural .' in Trash'
    );

        //Define all the arguments for this post type.
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 6,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-site',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'delete_with_user'    => false,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        // 'capabilities' => array(),
        'rewrite'             => array( 
            'slug' => strtolower( $plural_slug ),
            'with_front' => true,
            'pages' => true,
            'feeds' => false,

        ),
        'supports'            => array( 
            'title'
        )
    );

        //Create the post type using the above two varaiables.
    register_post_type( 'jobs', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'dwwp_register_post_type' );
```

Comment: don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Don't forget to flush rewrite rules on permalink setting page.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for `get_post_type`?

You can use it to get any CPT type by slug and use it conditionally

For instance:

```
function filter_the_content( $content ) {
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && 'my_cpt' == get_post_type() ) {
    return "Content reserved to logged in users";
  }

  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content' );
```

The docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/